# Move Gameobject to bottom of heirarchy using UnityScript

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

So i was wondering how to move an object to the bottom of the hierarchy inside of its parent. I am going to use it to put an image over another image. Please answer in **UNITYSCRIPT**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use these methods in `Transform`:

```
transform.SetAsFirstSibling ();
transform.SetAsLastSibling ();
transform.SetSiblingIndex (5);
```

The names of the methods tell everything you need, I think.